# Android 3rd Party Integration

Tags: java, android

Hi i tried to implement a 3rd party library from github. this is kinda crazy. I already worked often with 3rd party libarys. All I had to do was adding the compile command in the build gradle but in this case its something different. This is the github link of the lib i want to implement:

[Link to github](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

The problem is i dont have access to all components of this library. Only to the files in `com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.0:sources@jar`

But in the class ExpandableExampleActivity i have to import:

```
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.R;
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.common.data.AbstractExpandableDataProvider;
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.common.fragment.ExampleExpandableDataProviderFragment;
```

But i cant. I can see the files in the directory on github!!!

Can somebody help me how to integrate this the best way. Thx

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/xujiaao/mvn-repository/master/releases' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.xujiaao:aarLinkSources:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'aar-link-sources'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.oli.com.fitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.7.8'

    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    aarLinkSources 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.0:sources@jar'
}
```

Comment: Is this actually related to "R packages party and partykit for recursive partitioning"?

Comment: What? I dont understand that. I just want to integrate the whole library sucessfully.

Comment: XxGoliathusxX: you specified the "party" tag, whose summary includes the text @AndyTurner quoted. (I've removed the tag.)

Comment: I strongly suggest, clean and build project again. R class sometimes can not be created without clean compilation

Comment: The problem is not the R symbol. I just cant access all files.  if i type in 
import com.h6ah4i.android the only option i have beside * is "widget". But the classes i need are in com.h6ah4i.android.example.XXX.XXX

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see if you just need to import the three files,

```
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.R;
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.common.data.AbstractExpandableDataProvider;
import com.h6ah4i.android.example.advrecyclerview.common.fragment.ExampleExpandableDataProviderFragment;
```

Then just copy the last two files from the github project into your own. The R file would automatically be generated upon building the project. I don't see that the two files depend on other files, so it should work.

Comment: like i said: i dont have access to com.h6ah4i.android.EXAMPLE. And the imports above are just examples. I need a lot more.

Comment: Dude, it is there in the github folder, I have access, so you should have too !!

Comment: its all marked red an grey. when i import something and write a . the possible directories are shown, no example

Comment: i added my gradle build above^^

Comment: I mean to say just copy the classes from the github project and paste them in your project. By the way they are just examples and I think you need to implement your own. I don't have an idea about the library so may be this part is not what the lib is for.

Comment: Once you copy those three files into the project you find out that they link to a lot more. I don't think the github project wanted you to be able to take their code as a framework to work from. It's frustrating but im now removing all the data providers and seeing what i can swap in with my own code.